# Return the first day on previous month in Hive

Tags: hive

I try to return the count greater that first day of previous month from column 'dt' in HIVE table.

I use below, and don't work:

````
select count (*) from my_table 
where dt > from_unixtime(unix_tmestamp(dt,'yyyyMMdd'))```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get first day of previous month based on dt.
`add_months(trunc(dt,'MM'),-1)`

Trunc will truncate date and make it a first day of the month of dt.

Add months will negate 1 month from first day of the month of dt.
Screenshot of output.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately above function doesn't work. Function returns all records instead of first day of previous month. Format of my dt column it date like  2022-08-01

Comment: @SASUSER - i have added screenshot from my system. I think logically you should use this filter `where dt> add_months(trunc(current_date(),'MM'),-1)`. let me know if this works. If you still see issues, pls pose some sample data